# Graphical error with featured bar?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, design

[image]

Is the white space supposed to be there? I think it looks a little odd, and should span the entire width of the site. Am I the only one getting this?

Comment: What rather "offends me" is that the entire line is a link, so it doesn't really look like there's a link in the first place.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, but the intended design. As for @badp, blame us diamonds. We can reshape it so that only parts of it are links, if that's desired.

Comment: @Grace I'll ask Jin to put some `:hover` rule for `#system-message a`.

Comment: @badp While you're at it, get our hover on our ASK QUESTION button ♪

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think having the sides in white makes the message a lot more visible - as it breaks the otherwise straight line between the top section and the main section.

So I support Jin's "by-design" decision.